# Regarding LRU Cache Design using HashMap and Linked List combination

Tags: caching, data-structures, dictionary, hashmap, lru

Referring to [LRU cache design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504178/lru-cache-design/)

I have a question regarding the answer.

Say my hash map is full (the interviewer gave me a max size) [I understand if I need to fetch a pair already present in the map I'll move the list entry to the front to indicate recent use.]

But, what if I have an entry which is to be added and this key hashes to same position as a different key. (Collision) How do I go about it?

DO I do chaining or probing? If I do chaining, should I increase the map size?
If I remove the oldest entry it empties a location in my hash map. But a new entry might not hash to this location? It might hash to another full entry? (Different Key, Value Pair)
How to solve this?

Comment: Isn't this completely independent of the use in an LRU cache and just an implementation detail of the hash map?

Comment: yes, I updated the title too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design will not include chaining because we're here designing a direct mapped cache and this tradeoff is known that a direct mapped cache ONLY considers the recency of an entry before removing it from cache and not the frequency of being asked for.

The max size limit will be imposed on the linked list size and every time we try to add a new entry when the linked list is full, the last used entry (of linked list) and corresponding map entry is removed. The location where the new entry is to be inserted is independent of what was removed.

For more details on concurrency check out [this](http://code.google.com/p/concurrentlinkedhashmap/wiki/Design) link.

Comment: Nice link on LRU caches.

Answer (score 0):

size of map is number of key value pairs present in Map, so its independent of whether key value pairs are present in same hash bucket or different.
so if you check data structure of hashmap its array of linkedlist, so when there is hash collision there is chaining and size of map is also increased.
now if your new entry hashes to location which is not null you need to chain as we do in linkedlist.

PS: for LRU Cache you can see [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#LinkedHashMap%28int,%20float,%20boolean%29)