# C++ simple cache design for function output

Tags: c++, caching

I assume it's a quite frequent problem with well-known solutions, which I wasn't
able to find. So I'm seeking advice here.

## Problem Statement

Consider the following setting:

```
class A; // some class

const A f(const A&); // an _expensive_ function

void do_stuff()
{
    A a;

    a.modify(...);

    do_stuff1(f(a));  // compute f(a)
    do_stuff2(f(a));  // use cached value of f(a)

    a.modify(...);

    do_stuff3(f(a));  // recompute f(a)
}
```

I would like the return value of `f(a)` to be cached between the first and
second calls, but to be discarded after the second call to `a.modify()`.
**EDIT:** In practice, the calls to `f(a)` will be in different scopes.

Here are the pieces of solutions I've explored, for what it's worth.

## Solution 1: Central Cache

### Using time stamps

I can imagine a simple solution involving adding a time stamp to class `A` that
function `f` can check and decide if it needs to update its cached result,
stored somewhere in a central cache.  I guess this also implies changing the
signature of `f` to:

```
const A& f(const A&);
```

**Problem 1:** with a central cache, we need a mechanism to destroy the
cached result of `f(a)` when `a` is destroyed.

### Using hash codes

Aside from Problem 1, this seems simple enough. But it gets complicated when `A`
stands for `std::vector<...>`.  I guess dynamic polymorphism should be excluded
here.  So we forget about adding a time stamp to a subclass of `std::vector<...>` and all
the overriding that it would imply.  However, we could compute some hash code or UUID
based on the contents of `a` --- assuming that it is much cheaper than computing
`f(a)` --- and base the central cache on these hash codes.  But we're facing 
Problem 1 again.

## Solution 2: Coupled Objects

I still haven't found how to implement this, but the idea is to have `a` notify
the cache for `f(a)` when `a` is written to or destroyed, but not when it is
merely read from.  I can't figure how to do that without dynamic polymorphism,
and without slowing down single-element accesses using `operator[]` or
iterators by sending notifications to the cache for each modified element.

**Problem 2:** find a mechanism of delimiting sets of changes to `a` to invalidate the cache only once for each set of changes.

I've thought of proxies to enable write access on `a` (inspired by the concept
of mutex), but couldn't come up with any working code.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you store the `return` value and reuse it ? If you can change `f(const A&)`, then you can pass a temporary object of `A` as a 2nd parameter and use the same.

Comment: @Munger, you mentioned that `A` could be anything, even `std::vector<...>`. Is `A` anything? Is this theoretical or practical question? What is `A` exactly?

Comment: @Dialecticus: for the problem at hand, it's a `std::vector<...>`. But I recall facing that problem for other types of objects, so I wrote `A` to include these cases as well. Perhaps I shouldn't.

Comment: Is it much cheaper to compare two vectors than to call the function once? If those two operations cost roughly the same then there's not much room for optimization.

Comment: @Dialectus: Yes, it is much cheaper to compare vectors than to call the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done similar stuff with interfaces like this:

```
class F
{
public:
 virtual int f(int a)=0;
};

class Cache : public F
{
public:
   Cache(F &f) : f(f) { }
   int f(int a) { /*caching logic here, calls f.f() if not found from cache */ }
   F &f;
};

class Impl : public F
{
   int f(int a) { /* real implementation here */ }
};
```

Then it's just deciding where to use the caching logic:

```
   Impl i; 
   Cache c(i);
   c.f(10); // put to cache with key 10
   c.f(10); // found from cache
   c.f(11); // put to cache with key 11
```

Comment: I like that. But I still have to solve Problem 1 above.  `f` will be called on many different objects, so it is a bad idea to keep cached values of `f(old_a)` for all `old_a`'s that have been destroyed.

Comment: @munger destroying the cached values can happen in two different ways: either Cache object goes out of scope/gets destroyed/replaced, or you can add a member function to Cache which lets you explicitly remove some cached values or a range of values from the cache. The cache can have any member functions you like, so it's possible to do these things with this design.

Comment: I've managed to do what I need with a similar approach using boost::function, and by calling the cached version where the function is likely to be called more than once, and the uncached version elsewhere.   In the cache map, I replaced the vectors, which require a lot of storage, with SHA-1 hash values.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this:

```
const A &cacheA = f(a);
do_stuff1(cacheA);  // compute f(a)
do_stuff2(cacheA);  // use cached value of f(a)
```

Comment: Probably not. The shown code is a conceptual example, and the two calls to `f(a)` will probably be in completely unrelated parts of the code.

Comment: No, the code I've given above is overly simplified. The calls to f(a) actually occur in mutually exclusive scopes.

Comment: @Munger: Then you should edit your question and make it more clear that the calls will be in different scopes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm probably missing some important detail here, but can't you just use a [LRU cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639744/least-recently-used-cache-using-c) for this purpose?

Comment: Mainly because I already know the optimal life time of the cached objects, i.e. until destruction of the original objects.  Since in the specific application I have in mind, most of them are going to have a really short life time, a LRU cache would be a waste of memory. Good point, though.

Answer (score 1):

make f a member of A. Then you can decide in the instance of A if you can reuse the cached result or not.

Comment: In the specific application I have in mind, `f(a)` is just an alternative representation of `a`. So, for design reasons, what you suggest is the way I'd like to go, and my first idea. This raises two questions: (1) how to subclass std::vector that has no virtual members, and (2) when to set the *modified* flag of the object.